# Set presence unavailable using asmack

Tags: android, smack, asmack

I am using openfire and asmack lib. I am implementing **online** and **offline** button in android chat application .How can I set my presence "unavailable".

Note: I don't want to use **connection.disconnect()**  method ,because **

> This method cleans up all resources used by the connection. Therefore,
>   the roster, listeners and other stateful objects cannot be re-used by
>   simply calling connect() on this connection again. This is unlike the
>   behavior during unexpected disconnects (and subsequent connections).
>   In that case, all state is preserved to allow for more seamless error
>   recovery.

**

**But I need to reuse roster and listeners** when I click online button. So what should I do.

Comment: when i use this and use pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection); pingManager.registerPingFailedListener(this); pingManager.setPingInterval(32); than it not working as expetcted. i receiving push from XMPP even i send presence to unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can send unavaiable presence. it's: `new Presence(Type.unavaiable);` I work for me

Comment: Don't forget to actually send the presence packet

Comment: when i use this and use pingManager = PingManager.getInstanceFor(mConnection);
            pingManager.registerPingFailedListener(this);
            pingManager.setPingInterval(32); than it not working as expetcted. i receiving push from XMPP even i send presence to unavailable